# HTML/CSS (SCSS) - Image on top of every printing page

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

So, I have a small and simple page that looks like this:

[image: Page]

Normal view in the browser works perfect and everything is how I want it to have (with all the styles [margin, padding,..] etc.).

---

Now, My problem, or rather my question, is about the print view of this page.

As you can see in the above image, there is the "seperator"-image. The content#1 can be sometimes smaller, sometimes bigger (with texts etc.).

When content #1 is too big I want the seperator-image to show on top of the second page.

**Is there somehow a way to do that? (I think javascript has to be used for this (no jquery!).**

---

A image to show what I approximately want for the print view:

[image: print view]

---

I hope everything is understandable, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `@media print`  to simply create a page break before the seperator?

Comment: Oh wow, didnt know there is a page-break-property . For now that works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS has a [page-break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) property to include a page break before an element.

If you combine it with `@media print` you can select the 2nd image there and page break then on print pages:

```css
@media only print {
  img:nth-child(2) {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```